# Is there a way to link to the browser's (for example Chrome) "new tab" page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I want to create a button that when clicked, opens the "New tab" page. the page that suggests your most visited websites or is customized by you. In chrome it is accessible by typing "chrome://new-tab-page" in the address bar. How can I link to that?

Comment: I question the benefit of this…? Why would a user click on a button in a web page that opens a new tab, instead of on the "New Tab" button in their browser…?

Comment: Basicly `<a href="about:newtab">New Tab</a>`, but it's probably blocked due to the security issues.

Comment: dear @deceze, im glad you mentioned it. maybe there is a better way. my first problem was that chrome lacks a warning when you are closing a window with multiple tabs, and i dont want to use a third party extension. so i designed a local page as my homepage that provides this functionality. this functionality needs one click to be activated, and its nice if that click leads me to the page containing my most visited websites

Answer (score 0):

You could use `target="_blank"` to open a new tab

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools!</a>
```

read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

Comment: This is not what OP needs, they want to open the "New tab" tab like you'd clicked the "New tab" button on the browser (or hit CTRL+T).

Comment: thanks but as @Teemu mentioned i dont want to open a link in a new tab, i want a link that directs to the new tab page